# Apache Cordova and bluetooth

Tags: apache, cordova, bluetooth

Does Apache Cordova have the abilty to use the mobile device's bluetooth. I'm currently making an app on Android and it uses bluetooth but I would also like to make the same app on Apache Cordova and I can't find any type of documentation regarding using Apache Cordova and bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Cordova can make all platform APIs from iOS or Android available within a so called WebView. A WebView is basically rendering HTML, CSS and executing JavaScript. Platform APIs can be made available through plugins in Apache Cordova and inside the WebView can be used via JavaScript. You can either write your own plugin or use an existing one.

Android allows for Bluetooth classic and Bluetooth low energy. To my best knowledge iOS only has support for Bluetooth low energy. There are several plugins available for bluetooth support inside an Apache Cordova app, just use the plugin search on the Apache Cordova Website: https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

Ranked by github stars you might use the following plugin for bluetooth le:
https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle

Or the following for bluetooth classic:
https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

Comment: BluetoothSerial is not to use between two same devices like android to android or IOS to IOS

Answer (score 1):

@AdamV,
You'll have to use a plugin. Most anything you want to do on Phonegap requires a plugin.

My list (duplicate of Phonegap offical, list on page)

http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/plugins/list_of_plugins.html

The Cordova version:

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=bluetooth